# How to put <Tag> inside src / href

Tags: javascript, php, html

What I'm trying to accomplish is using DOM cloneNode() to get an element by tag name and clone it to another tag (inside URL).

So basically I want to put `<tag>` or `<div class="tag">`
inside the *src* or *href* attributes of another tag.

for example:

```
    <body onload="myFunction()">
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var itm = document.getElementsByTagName("tag1")[0].lastChild;
    var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementsByTagName("tag2")[0].appendChild(cln);
    }
    </script>


    <tag1>Hello.png</tag1>


    <a href='http://example.com/<tag2></tag2>'> </a>
```

so the result should be:

```
    <a href='http://example.com/Hello.png'> </a>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  It would help to know that.  This is probably not the way to do whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: put < div class="tag" > in a variable and print it after the url.Can you rewrite your question? Not much,just enough to make it readable

Comment: You are probably looking for the fragment identifier. [Url.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hash).

Comment: I rewrote the question, sorry for not being clear the first time

Comment: So are you trying to get the src of an image ? If you have already that image in website ,just copy its src and paste it

Comment: That image name is generated randomly in every webpage. i put it inside < tag1 > so that when ever it change it will clone the name of the image to < tag2 >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Element.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to update the *href* or *src* attributes, by replacing the string (i.e. `<tag2></tag2>`) using [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property of `<tag1>`.

Run the snippet below and press the button labeled "**Copy**". Note that [encodeURI()](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mdn+encodeuri) is used because the `<tag2>` is actually encoded as far as the DOM property is concerned (i.e. it isn't a separate HTML tag).

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(DOMLoadEvent) {
  document.getElementById('copy').addEventListener('click', copyTag1);
});

function copyTag1() {
  var innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("tag1")[0].innerHTML;
  var link = document.getElementById('link');
  console.log('link.href before: ',link.href, 'innerhtml: ',innerHTML);
  link.setAttribute('href', link.href.replace(encodeURI('<tag2></tag2>'),innerHTML));
  console.log('link.href after: ',link.href);
}
```

```html
<button id="copy">Copy</button>
<tag1>Hello.png</tag1>
<a id="link" href='http://example.com/<tag2></tag2>'> Example Link</a>
```